# Access form - tab through columns not rows (not the first column), also only fields that are > 0

Tags: tabs, ms-access-2007

I've used the tab index and tab stop options in access but I want to tab through a column instead of through rows.

Within a form, I have a table which has three columns, the third contains integers and is the only column that I want to tab through.  I would also preferably like to only tab through fields within the column that are not zero.

Currently, on pressing tab it goes through each field in each row of the table within the form.

I would be very grateful for any advice offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the key, the following comprises a mix of notes.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

If (Shift And acShiftMask) > 0 Then
    If KeyCode = 9 Then
        KeyCode = 0
        If Not Me.Recordset.BOF Then
            Me.Recordset.MovePrevious
        End If
    End If
End If

Select Case KeyCode
    Case 38
        KeyCode = 0
        If Not Me.Recordset.BOF Then
            Me.Recordset.MovePrevious
        End If
    ''Arrow down or tab
    Case 40, 9
        KeyCode = 0
        If Not Me.Recordset.EOF Then
            Me.Recordset.MoveNext
        End If
End Select
End Sub
```

You will have to set KeyPreview to Yes. The code for tab is 9.